# Turning a string of text into individual rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, string, list, column

I have a series of letters in Excel I would like to turn into individual rows. Is there a simple command to do this instead of using text to column and separating through each one.

The list is as follows:

```
IKELKMSKDEIKREYKEMEGSPEIKSKRRQFHQEIQSGNMRENVKRSSVVVADPTHIAIGILYKRGETPLPLVTFKYTDAQVQTVRKIAEEEGVPILQRIPLARALYWDALVDHYIPAEQIEATAEVLRWLERQNIEKQHSEML
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who care about an answer when they research the subject, the following would turn the string into a column with one letter in each row's cell:

```
=MID(A1,  SEQUENCE(  LEN(A1)  ),  1)
```

and if preferred as a single row across the columns:

```
=MID(A1,  SEQUENCE(  1,  LEN(A1)  ),  1)
```

Of course, one can use just one of them and wrap it in the `TRANSPOSE()` function to change its output's orientation.